# bash 4.3 (`bash-4.3$` ) appear in my GNOME terminal emulator for fedora 25 can someboby help me to fix it back and remove the bash 4.3

Tags: fedora, prompt, gnome-terminal

This  way it start `bash-4.3$`

When I execute `su` it show this `[root@localhost harrugg2]#`

I have tried to edit .bashrc and .bashrc_profile but nothing changes.

This my .bashrc file

```
 # .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

This my .bashrc_profile

```
"~/.bashrc_profile" [New File]
```

this my ~/.profile

```
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
"~/.profile" [New File]
```

this my ~/.bash_profile

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
"~/.bash_profile" 12L, 176C
```

this my /etc/bashrc

```
# /etc/bashrc

# System wide functions and aliases
# Environment stuff goes in /etc/profile

# It's NOT a good idea to change this file unless you know what you
# are doing. It's much better to create a custom.sh shell script in
# /etc/profile.d/ to make custom changes to your environment, as this
# will prevent the need for merging in future updates.

# are we an interactive shell?
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ -z "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ]; then
    case $TERM in
    xterm*|vte*)
      if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm ]; then
          PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm
      elif [ "${VTE_VERSION:-0}" -ge 3405 ]; then
          PROMPT_COMMAND="__vte_prompt_command"
      else
          PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"'
      fi
      ;;
    screen*)
      if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen ]; then
          PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen
      else
          PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033k%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"'
      fi
      ;;
    *)
      [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-default ] && PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-default
      ;;
    esac
  fi
  # Turn on parallel history
  shopt -s histappend
  history -a
  # Turn on checkwinsize
  shopt -s checkwinsize
  [ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "
  # You might want to have e.g. tty in prompt (e.g. more virtual machines)
  # and console windows
  # If you want to do so, just add e.g.
  # if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  #   PS1="[\u@\h:\l \W]\\$ "
  # fi
  # to your custom modification shell script in /etc/profile.d/ directory
fi

if ! shopt -q login_shell ; then # We're not a login shell
    # Need to redefine pathmunge, it get's undefined at the end of /etc/profile
    pathmunge () {
        case ":${PATH}:" in
            *:"$1":*)
                ;;
            *)
                if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                    PATH=$PATH:$1
                else
                    PATH=$1:$PATH
                fi
        esac
    }

    # By default, we want umask to get set. This sets it for non-login shell.
    # Current threshold for system reserved uid/gids is 200
    # You could check uidgid reservation validity in
    # /usr/share/doc/setup-*/uidgid file
    if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`id -gn`" = "`id -un`" ]; then
       umask 002
    else
       umask 022
    fi

    SHELL=/bin/bash
    # Only display echos from profile.d scripts if we are no login shell
    # and interactive - otherwise just process them to set envvars
    for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
        if [ -r "$i" ]; then
            if [ "$PS1" ]; then
                . "$i"
            else
                . "$i" >/dev/null
            fi
        fi
    done

    unset i
    unset -f pathmunge
fi
# vim:ts=4:sw=4
```

this my /etc/profile

```
# /etc/profile

# System wide environment and startup programs, for login setup
# Functions and aliases go in /etc/bashrc

# It's NOT a good idea to change this file unless you know what you
# are doing. It's much better to create a custom.sh shell script in
# /etc/profile.d/ to make custom changes to your environment, as this
# will prevent the need for merging in future updates.

pathmunge () {
    case ":${PATH}:" in
        *:"$1":*)
            ;;
        *)
            if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                PATH=$PATH:$1
            else
                PATH=$1:$PATH
            fi
    esac
}


if [ -x /usr/bin/id ]; then
    if [ -z "$EUID" ]; then
        # ksh workaround
        EUID=`id -u`
        UID=`id -ru`
    fi
    USER="`id -un`"
    LOGNAME=$USER
    MAIL="/var/spool/mail/$USER"
fi

# Path manipulation
if [ "$EUID" = "0" ]; then
    pathmunge /usr/sbin
    pathmunge /usr/local/sbin
else
    pathmunge /usr/local/sbin after
    pathmunge /usr/sbin after
fi

HOSTNAME=`/usr/bin/hostname 2>/dev/null`
HISTSIZE=1000
if [ "$HISTCONTROL" = "ignorespace" ] ; then
    export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
else
    export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
fi

export PATH USER LOGNAME MAIL HOSTNAME HISTSIZE HISTCONTROL

# By default, we want umask to get set. This sets it for login shell
# Current threshold for system reserved uid/gids is 200
# You could check uidgid reservation validity in
# /usr/share/doc/setup-*/uidgid file
if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`id -gn`" = "`id -un`" ]; then
    umask 002
else
    umask 022
fi

for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then 
            . "$i"
        else
            . "$i" >/dev/null
        fi
    fi
done

unset i
unset -f pathmunge
```

Comment: @harri Your `.bash_profile` does source `~/.bashrc`, so adding `PS1=stuff` after the `fi` in `.bashrc` _should_ have effect no matter what. I'm not sure what the problem is

Comment: @fox let me try adding `PS1=stuff `to my .bashrc file and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't like the prompt you have as regular user

[This page describe how to change your prompt](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)

Running the following command will change your prompt:

```
PS1="[\\u@\\h:\\w] $"
```

> will result with **[username@hostname:working-directory] $**

If you like your prompt to be only `$` you can use the following line:

```
PS1="$ "
```

Adding the above line to your `~/.bashrc` will set your prompt everything you logged-in

> **PS1** – The value of this parameter is expanded (see PROMPTING below) and used as the primary prompt string. The default value is
>   \s-\v\$ .
>
> Bash allows these prompt strings to be customized by inserting a
>   number of backslash-escaped special characters that are decoded as
>   follows:

```
\a : an ASCII bell character (07)
\d : the date in “Weekday Month Date” format (e.g., “Tue May 26”)
\D{format} : the format is passed to strftime(3) and the result is inserted into the prompt string; an empty format results in a locale-specific time representation. The braces are required
\e : an ASCII escape character (033)
\h : the hostname up to the first ‘.’
\H : the hostname
\j : the number of jobs currently managed by the shell
\l : the basename of the shellâ€™s terminal device name
\n : newline
\r : carriage return
\s : the name of the shell, the basename of $0 (the portion following the final slash)
\t : the current time in 24-hour HH:MM:SS format
\T : the current time in 12-hour HH:MM:SS format
\@ : the current time in 12-hour am/pm format
\A : the current time in 24-hour HH:MM format
\u : the username of the current user
\v : the version of bash (e.g., 2.00)
\V : the release of bash, version + patch level (e.g., 2.00.0)
\w : the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
\W : the basename of the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
\! : the history number of this command
\# : the command number of this command
\$ : if the effective UID is 0, a #, otherwise a $
\nnn : the character corresponding to the octal number nnn
\\ : a backslash
\[ : begin a sequence of non-printing characters, which could be used to embed a terminal control sequence into the prompt
\] : end a sequence of non-printing characters
```

Comment: where exactly should i add the line in .bashrc

Comment: @harri - you can add it at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file, you'll see the change the next time you'll enter into a new terminal

Comment: nothing is changing still the same eve after adding the line `PS1="$ "` bash4.3 still appear in my terminal.

Comment: did you executing `PS1="$"` in terminal, and nothing changed after your hit Enter?

Comment: this what that appear in the terminal                                            `bash-4.3$ PS1="$"`
`$`

Comment: And after another pressing  Enter several times? do you see `$` as your new prompt?

Comment: yah i `$` after pressing enter

Comment: Now, try setting `PS1="[\\u@\\h:\\w] $"` , and press Enter a few times afterwards.

Comment: @harri  what happen when you open a new terminal, and execute `. "$HOME/.bashrc"`? do you see any change in your prompt?

Comment: this what happen when i press enter `bash-4.3$ PS1="[\\u@\\h:\\w] $"`
`[harrugg2@localhost:~] $`
`[harrugg2@localhost:~] $`
`[harrugg2@localhost:~] $`
`[harrugg2@localhost:~] $`

Comment: @harri - so setting `PS1` variable manually is working in your `bash`

Comment: `bash-4.3$ . "$HOME/.bashrc"`
`bash-4.3$ `

Comment: YAH but its working manually but after closing the terminal and opening a new one the bash 4.3 still appear in my terminal

Comment: @harri please execute `su` and afterwards `cat ~root/.profile` and `cat ~root/.bashrc` and add the result to the question

Comment: `bash-4.3$ su`
`Password: `
`[root@localhost harrugg2]# cat ~root/.profile`
`[root@localhost harrugg2]# cat ~root/.bashrc`
`# .bashrc`

`alias rm='rm -i'`
`alias cp='cp -i'`
`alias mv='mv -i'`

`# Source global definitions`
`if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then`
 `. /etc/bashrc`
`fi`
`[root@localhost harrugg2]# `

Comment: the above is the result