# Terminal shows sh-4.4 not a default terminal

Tags: shell

My terminal shows sh-4.4# when I log in as root through VNC viewer. But if I log in to the system physically then it shows root@hostname like normal. How can I fix it on the viewer?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: In which dotfile do you define PS1? VNC Viewer might not be giving you a login shell. Does VNC Viewer provide an option for that?

Comment: What command did you tell the VNC Server to run?

Comment: Ironically, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/453439/5132 is an exact duplicate but the main part of the problem is elsewhere.  Other less apparent but in fact more on-point duplicates are https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/363522/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/236005/5132 , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421351/5132 .  Doubtless many more, but that's where I stopped looking.  This gets asked over and over.